# Using SQL Express edition commercially

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-express, sql-server-2005-express

Can I use SQL Server Express edition for commercial use?

Can our clients redistribute SQL Server Express edition with their application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To redistribute SQL Server Express, you need to obtain [redistribution rights](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/express/redistregister.aspx) from Microsoft. And yes, you can use it for commercial use (see, for example, this [FAQ](http://www.microsoft.com/express/support/faq/)).

> What are the Visual Studio Express Editions?
>
> SQL Server 2008 Express and SQL Server Compact Edition – A powerful and easy-to-use set of databases to complement each Express Edition
>
> Can I use Express Editions for commercial use?
>
> Yes, there are no licensing restrictions for applications built using Visual Studio Express Editions.